Which sheaves are good for calculating extraordinary restriction?
Let $X$ be a sufficiently nice locally compact Hausdorff space and let $i:Y\subset X$ be the inclusion map of a sufficiently nice closed subspace. For example, one could take $X$ to be a locally finite polyhedron and $Y$ a closed subpolyhedron. Let also $Sh(-)$ denote the category of complexes of sheaves of $R$-modules where $R$ is a ring (commutative, associative, with identity). Set $Sh^+(X)\subset Sh(X)$ to be the full subcategory of complexes bounded below.
There is the left exact functor $i_Y:Sh(X)\to Sh(Y)$ obtained by sheafifying the sections with support in $Y$. The right derived functor $Ri_Y:D Sh(X)\to DSh(Y)$ is denoted $i^!$ and called the extraordinary restriction functor. Here $D$ stands for derived category, i.e. localization in quasi-isomorphisms. A class $\mathcal{C}$ of objects of $Sh(X)$ is good for calculating $i^!$ if (a) for every $S^\ast\in Sh(X)$ there is a quasi-isomorphism $S^\ast\to I^\ast$ for some $I^\ast\in \mathcal{C}$; (b) $i_Y$ preserves quasi-isomorphisms between objects of $\mathcal{C}$. Given such a class, one can calculate $i^!$ on any object $[S^\ast]\in DSh(X)$ by first resolving $S^\ast$ by an element of $\mathcal{C}$ and then applying $i_Y$. Similar definitions/remarks apply in the case of complexes bounded below.
My question is: is the class of term-wise $c$-soft sheaves inside $Sh^\ast(X)$ good for calculating $i^!$ if (a) $\ast=\varnothing$; (b) $\ast=+$? If the answer turns out to be no in either case, then is there a reasonably large class of complexes that can still do the job? Here "reasonably large" means "larger than $K$-injective".
Remark. It is not hard to check that for complexes bounded below (i.e. $\ast=+$) term-wise flabby complexes will do. Not sure about the unbounded case.
